# WPF - How to put alphabetical index on right side of a list view

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am a mobile app developer and know that we can use index list to display tableview index in iOS.

Is there any similar control available for WPF list view ?  Need custom list view with index on right side of a list view. Any idea/suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

[image: We need this control in WPF]

Answer (score 1):

I think the literal answer is no.

There is no straight-out-the-box control would give you this functionality.

You can build one though.

Fill an Itemscontrol with a-z or by picking out the first letters of content which the listbox definitely has.

At a minimum, you'd then find the appropriate item and use bringintoview on it. Or something more sophisticated to move it to the top of the visible area of your listbox/view or whatever that is.